# Adjusting macro to copy range in table but placing the range at the first blank line in the table

Tags: vba, excel, copy, range

I'm using the following code to copy a block of data into another worksheet which holds all the data as a table. The code is used to copy after each time people fill in new data.

```
Sub Containersgeproduceerd()

    Worksheets("Production shift summary").Range("A76:J85").Copy
        Worksheets("Production perform container").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

The range of the block can be filled in totally or partially.
Whe the range is filled in partially and I copy it to the table and do that multiple times, I get the effect that the next copy starts at end range of the copied block in the table, thus if the range is not totally filled it leaves blank lines in the table after multiple times copying a partially filled range in the table.

What I want is that the data is copied into the first blank line.

Comment: Using ColA and End(xlUp) has the disadvantage that if a user leaves empty cells in the forst column of the copied range there's a chance that the next copy/paste may overwrite some of the previously-copied data.

Comment: if you have blank cells but not a complete blank row or column look at the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx). Unfortunately, it is impossible to speculate further without seeing data.

Comment: @tim - I believe the primary problem is that the OP is copying a static block (e.g. `Range("A76:J85")`) every time whether it is filled or not.

Comment: @Jeeped - If there are blank rows at the end of the source range then they should get overwritten by the next paste...

Comment: ...unless of course the first source rows are empty - updated my answer...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not yet allowed to post attachments else I would attach the document. I have almost no knowledge of VBA but this technique I've needed very much since many past registration files have been setup in block and its a way to keep people working in blocks but storing the data in tidy tables.

Answer (score 1):

This will copy any row from the source range which has at least one value entered.

```
Sub Containersgeproduceerd()

    Dim c As Range, rngCopy As Range, rw As Range

    Set rngCopy = Worksheets("Production shift summary").Range("A76:J85")

    'find empty cell in ColA
    Set c = Worksheets("Production perform container").Range( _
                         "A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'make sure destination row is blank
    Do While Application.CountA(c.Resize(1, rngCopy.Columns.Count)) > 0
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    'copy any row in the source range which has at least one value entered...
    For Each rw In rngCopy.Rows
        If Application.CountA(rw) > 0 Then
            c.Resize(1, rw.Cells.Count).Value = rw.Value
            Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next rw

End Sub
```